# using ElementIsVisible in Page Factory Model

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, wait

I am attempting to set up a Page Factory Model Framework using Selenium in C#

I have got my tests running using Selenium but want to separate out my Tests from the Framework.

Several tests require me to wait for an element to be visible before I do anything with the element. In my other versions of my Selenium testing I would do something like

```
By selector = By.XPath("/html/body/header/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[2]/span[2]");
            new WebDriverWait(driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(selector));
```

However I cant get Element Is Visible to work so have used Wait Until Visible in my Extension Method (Code Below).

When I run my test even with the Wait Until Visible Selenium is not waiting for the Element to appear before continuing. When I Debug the test it is failing with a stackOverflow at the WaitUntilVisible step.

When I run the test normally I am getting the message does not show error, however it is showing (I can see it on the screen). I know from experience of running this test in my alternative frameworks that this is simply because the test is looking for the element before it has appeared.

I am already running an ImplicitWait as part of my Browser Factory Class.

Am I understanding and using my waits correctly in the Page Factory Model?

Test I am running

```
[Test]
        public void Framework_Invalid_Location()
        {
            BrowserFactory.InitBrowser("Chrome");
            BrowserFactory.LoadApplication("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            Page.HomePage.SearchForRestaurant("CFYUGHGYHYTDFD");
            Assert.That(Page.HomePage.InvalidPostcode(), Is.EqualTo("Please enter a valid location or postcode"), "message does not show");
            BrowserFactory.CloseAllDrivers();
        }
```

HomePage Class

```
        private IWebDriver driver;
        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#js-postcode")]
        [CacheLookup]
        private IWebElement PostcodeInput { get; set; }



        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "/html/body/header/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[2]/span[2]")]
        [CacheLookup]                     
        private IWebElement ErrorMessageInvalidEntry { get; set; }


        public void SearchForRestaurant(string Postcode)
        {
            PostcodeInput.SendKeys(Postcode);
            SearchButton.ClickOnIt("SearchButton");



        public string InvalidPostcode()
        {
            ErrorMessageInvalidEntry.WaitUntilVisible(10);
            return ErrorMessageInvalidEntry.Text;
        }
```

Element Extension function I am calling for my Wait. Updated from comments and suggestions

public static void Wait(this IWebElement element, IWebDriver driver, float TimeOut)
    {

```
    WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeOut));
    return Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(element));
```

There is still one error with this code for (element)
Cannot convert from OpenQa.Selenium.IWebElement to open.Qa.Selenium.By

Really feel I am at the very edge of the little knowledge I have learnt over the past few months so thankyou for all help.

Page Class

```
namespace KukdFramework.PageObjects
{
    public class Page
    {
        private static T GetPage<T>() where T : new()


        public static HomePage HomePage
        {
            get { return GetPage<HomePage>(); }
        }
```

Browser Factory Code

```
 private static readonly IDictionary<string, IWebDriver> Drivers = new Dictionary<string, IWebDriver>();
        private static IWebDriver driver;

        public static IWebDriver Driver
        {
            get
            {
                if (driver == null)
                    throw new NullReferenceException("The WebDriver browser instance was not initialized. You should first call the method InitBrowser.");
                return driver;
            }
            private set
            {
                driver = value;
            }
        }

        public static void InitBrowser(string browserName)
        {
            switch (browserName)
            {
                case "Firefox":
                    if (driver == null)
                    {
                        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                        Drivers.Add("Firefox", Driver);
                        BrowserSettings();

                    }
                    break;

                case "IE":
                    if (driver == null)
                    {
                        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                        Drivers.Add("IE", Driver);
                        BrowserSettings();
                    }
                    break;

                case "Chrome":
                    if (driver == null)
                    {
                        driver = new ChromeDriver();
                        Drivers.Add("Chrome", Driver);
                        BrowserSettings();
                    }
                    break;
            }
```

}

Comment: few things, remove unncessary code, you have pasted so much code which is not nedded. I guess `WaitUntilVisible` is not working as expected, right? what is happening. any error or exception or it's not working. please update the question rather than replying in comment.

Comment: I have updated the post, I had included all the code to try and show the structure of my Framework. Because this is all new to me I wasn't sure if there was something fundamental I was doing wrong to begin with that was causing this issue.

Comment: what is the stacktrace, I don't much C# but seems like `WaitUntilVisible` is custom function and not provided by webdriver. Can you update the question with implementation of `WaitUntilVisible` and stack-trace.

Comment: have amended my code given both Jordans Comment and what I had myself realised. However still cant get WebDriverWait to work correctly.

Comment: I don't think that was the case, i think `WaitUntilVisible` is a overloaded method. you should search for the implementation, also I don't see any stacktrace.

Comment: @Guarang Shah C# has extension methods which allow for some syntactic sugar.  OP's above extension method is called in C#:

`myElement.WaitUntilVisibile(time)` and can be translated to:

`MyWaitExtensionsClass.WaitUntilVisible(myElement, time)`

I do not believe Java has support for extension methods in this way (I think Java 8 has Default methods?).  More info on that can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096421/java-8-add-extension-default-method-to-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `WaitUntilVisible()` extension method calls itself recursively with no way out.

This will cause a stack overflow exception.

Instead of calling this method recursively, you could put your above `WebDriverWait` call inside this method and the return the found `IWebElement`.

**UPDATE (from comments):**
You'll need to pass in the `WebDriver` instance as well.  In your above `WebDriverWait` line you use `driver.Instance`.

Another option would be to modify the extension method to require an instance of `WebDriverWait` instead of just a `float` for waiting time.  This way you wouldn't need to pass the driver object in by itself.

Comment: As you posted this I realised my mistake there.

Comment: Ok tried putting my WebDriver wait command inside the method                        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); However I am getting an error now stating WebDriverWait does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Ok tried doing that have updated code accordingly, 2 issues now appearing I have annotated the code accordingly.

Comment: Seem to have resolved the driver issues but still have an issue passing the element into the Function (cannot convert from .IWebElement to .By)

Comment: have marked this as solved as I have moved beyond the original issue, will create a new post for the new specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an C# programmer, however JAVA and C# is similar and so you can probably convert following Java Code.

*WaitUntilVisible* Should look like this

```
public static void WaitUntilVisible(WebElement element, int timeOut){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}
```